# Connecting to a 2.5" laptop drive using USB

Tags: mac, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

So I swapped my MBP hard drive with a SSD drive, and I want to connect to my old hard drive.

I bought a nextstar 3 external 2.5" drive enclosure that has a USB 2.0 interface.  I watched an online video of an older version of the enclosure, and in the video they had a ATA cable to connect to the drive.  My enclosure didn't come with anything like that, and there doesn't seem to be a way to connect to my drive (my old drive is a seagate 500gb momentus 7200 RPM).

My laptop is about 2 years old now (MBP 17").

The drive doesnt' have pins to connect, it has a wide plug type connector, and a USB connector also (I was able to directly plugin the USB cable to the drive, but didn't connect it to my computer, was just testing thigns out).

Is it safe for me to directly connect the cable that came with the enclosure to the drive, and then connect the other end to my computer?  Does this single cable provide power and data transfer?

Answer (score 4):

I Seagate momentus is a normal SATA drive. It should have two connectors on the drive. One for power, one for data. (See red markings in the picture).

[image: Picture of a seagate momentus 2.5 inch HDD]

You 2½ inch case should:

- Either have cables which fit these
- Or a back plate with fixed connectors.
  You just 'slide' both connectors in place as you place the drive. (See the 2nd picture.)
- Or it has a 44 pins connector. In which case you bought the wrong enclosure. (One meant for old PATA laptop drives.

[image: image of a back plate in a 2.5 inch enclosure]